# Sequence such that $E_{n} \to E$ and $m(\cup E_{n}) = \infty$ then $\lim_{n} m(E_{n}) > m(\lim_{n} E_{n})$ (Example)

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

I proved that

> If $(E_{n})$ is a sequence of measurable sets such that $E_{n} \to E$ and $m(\cup E_{n}) < \infty$, then $\lim_{n} m(E_{n}) = m(\lim_{n} E_{n})$.

Now, I'm trying to find a example when $E_{n} \to E$ and $m(\cup E_{n}) = \infty$ such that $\lim_{n} m(E_{n}) > m(\lim_{n} E_{n})$ but I didn't succeed. Can anybody help me?

Comment: What is meant by $E_n\to E$?

Comment: @amsmath, sorry for the terrible notation. I want meant "$(E_{n})$ converges"

Comment: What is meant by this? Do you mean $E_1\subset E_2\subset\ldots$ and $E = \bigcup_n E_n$?

Comment: @amsmath This is fairly standard. $E_n \to E$ means $\lim \sup E_n =\lim \inf E_n =E$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Thanks!

Comment: @amsmath Or (exercise) equivalently, that $\chi_{E_n}\to\chi_E$ pointwise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E_n=[n,\infty)$ is an obvious example.